# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException due to mapping 2 xml files (orm.xml and springConfiguration.xml)

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with a spring project (Version 4.0.2).
I share the following files:

**The [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpNPP.png) of my project**.

**spring.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao" />
  
    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
 
    <bean id="employeeDAOJDBCTemplate" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDAOJDBCTemplateImpl">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
 
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdb" />
 <property name="username" value="root" />
 <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
 
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/orm.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**orm.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
  
    <named-query name="Employee.findAll">
        <query>SELECT e FROM Employee e</query>
    </named-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

**TodoRepository.java**

```js
public interface TodoRepository extends Repository<Employee, Long>
{
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Employee> findAll();
}
```

**TodoRepositoryBean.java**

```js
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TodoRepositoryBean
{
 @Autowired
 private TodoRepository todoRepository;
 
 public void doSomething(ActionEvent evt) 
 {
  List<Employee> les = todoRepository.findAll();
  for(Employee e : les)
  {
   System.out.println("Employee Name is: " + e.getName());
  }
 }
}
```

**test button**

```html
<p:commandButton value="Add" 
                 actionListener="#{todoRepositoryBean.doSomething}"/>
```

after clicking on this button, this exception appears:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.acme.esprit.utils.TodoRepositoryBean.doSomething(TodoRepositoryBean.java:31)

Have you please any idea about solving this issue.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can change your spring xml config to the following . You have missed the jpa repository bean description

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="your repository package" />
       ....

</beans>
```

Comment: Hello @DanHunex thanks for your help.As I shared, I made changes on the file spring.xml as you recommended but the exception persists. If you don't mind could you please take a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Liliya I have updated the xml config.  change it that way

Comment: Hello Sir @DanHunex, I'm glad for your replay. I affected the modification as you proposed. Unfortunately, the same exception was displayed. I share the structure of my project, could you please tell me if I made error. Thanks a lot.